# Static analysis of .net assembly

Tags: static, analysis, reflector, il

I have a C# project for which I need to find the all private methods which are not called from any other public method directly or indirectly.

In addition, for each private method which is called from a public method, I need to know which public method it is. Then I will detemine if that method is really called from a client of the class and if not I will be able to remove it.

In the past I used a code from Lutz Rorder which is the base of Reflector - it had an option to analyze IL code and gave object model on top of it. I cannot find this code now.

Any suggestion?
Maybe a point to that Lutz Rorder code?

Saar

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [Nitriq Static Code Analysis for .Net](http://www.nitriq.com) - They have a free community edition and their full blown license is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed Thomas the tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help you to find unused code in a .NET code base. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool.*

NDepend proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html) (hence detect unused method, ctor, property getter/setter...)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

NDepend is integrated in Visual Studio, thus these rules can be [checked/browsed/edited right inside the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). The tool can also be integrated into your CI process and it can build [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show rules violated and culprit code elements.

If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.

---

> In addition, for each private method which is called from a public method, I need to know which public method it is.

To obtain this information, with CQLinq you just need to write:

```
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsPrivate
let publicMethodsCallingMe = m.MethodsCallingMe.Where(m1 => m1.IsPublic)
where publicMethodsCallingMe.Count() > 0
select new { m, publicMethodsCallingMe }
```

The query result will be easily browsable:

[image: Browsing CQLinq query result]

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only method to do this (at least the only one that I know...) implies the use of a commercial (but not so expensive) tool, namely [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Among many other things, you can write SQL-like queries against your compiled assemblies, which allows for very fine-grained analysis. They call it CQL, the syntax is self-explaining, and NDepend's IntelliSense/auto-completion support as well as the general help/documentation are quite good.

(AFAIK they also provide a fully-featured trial, if that helps you...)

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will fulfil all these needs, but FXCop will do most of these for you and will help do a whole lot of coding standards as well. It's worth running over your c# code either way.

[FXCop (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: FxCop will find unused private methods. As for those that are used, right-click on the method and choose "Find All References" from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Reflector still has this functionality. Just right click the method, and click Analyze. Follow the links in the tree view.

You do not say whether you need to do it in code, or just 'visually'.

If needed for code, I am sure you can use the Reflector SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help you with this one using the Query Editor in the PowerCommands for Reflector addin (http://powercommands.codeplex.com) ... I'll see what I can come up with tonight, then let you know tomorrow.

Otherwise you could also write a quick application using the CCI or Cecil that would do it.

Query:

```
from a in AssemblyManager.Assemblies.Cast<IAssembly>()
where a.Name != "mscorlib" 
    && !a.Name.Contains("System")
from m in a.Modules.Cast<IModule>()
from t in m.Types.Cast<ITypeDeclaration>()
from mt in t.Methods.Cast<IMethodDeclaration>()
where mt.Visibility == MethodVisibility.Public 
    && !mt.RuntimeSpecialName 
    && !mt.SpecialName 
    && mt.Body is IMethodBody
from i in ((IMethodBody)mt.Body).Instructions.Cast<IInstruction>()
where i != null 
    && i.Value != null 
    && i.Value is IMethodReference 
    && ((IMethodReference)i.Value).Resolve() != null
    && ((IMethodReference)i.Value).Resolve().Visibility == MethodVisibility.Private
select new { 
    CallingMethod=t.Namespace + "." + t.Name + "." + mt.Name, 
    PrivateReferencedMethod=((ITypeReference)((IMemberReference)((IMethodReference)i.Value).Resolve()).DeclaringType).Namespace + "."
        + ((ITypeReference)((IMemberReference)((IMethodReference)i.Value).Resolve()).DeclaringType).Name + "."
        + ((IMethodReference)i.Value).ToString()
}
```

Comment: After reading your question for the second time - if you are interested in writihg a utility that does what you are looking for - then check out: http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you want to try getting the information from Reflector, you can use the following query to get all the private methods that are called by a public method.

NOTE: The assumption is all of your dependencies are loaded into Reflector already ... if you get a dialog asking to locate an assembly you'll have to click 'Skip' or it will kill Reflector.

Comment: I have also added filtering to ignore mscorlib or any System assembly as well as ignore special named methods (constructors and property methods).

Comment: I have a blog entry that introduces the Query Editor here: http://www.jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2009/10/18/Getting-Started-with-Query-Editor.aspx, I should have another one with more detail out in the next day or two.